# ViewModel Unit Testing (JUnit5, CoroutineDispatcher, Turbine, Mockk) Not working as expected

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit5, kotlin-stateflow, turbine

I'm trying to understand how [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) works with `StateFlow`.

> HelloWorldViewModel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class HelloWorldViewModel(
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    private val doOperationUseCase: DoOperationUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<HelloWorldState> = MutableStateFlow(HelloWorldState())
    val state: StateFlow<HelloWorldState> = _state.asStateFlow()

    fun doOperation() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _state.emit(state.value.copy(loading = true))
            doOperationUseCase()
            _state.emit(state.value.copy(loading = false))
        }
    }

}
```

> HelloWorldState

```
data class HelloWorldState(val loading: Boolean = false)
```

> DoOperationUseCase

```
class DoOperationUseCase {
    suspend operator fun invoke(): Result<List<String>> {
        delay(500)
        return Result.success(listOf("1"))
    }
}
```

> HelloWorldViewModelTest

```
import app.cash.turbine.test
import io.mockk.coEvery
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.UnconfinedTestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class HelloWorldViewModelTest {

    private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    @MockK
    lateinit var doOperationUseCase: DoOperationUseCase

    private lateinit var classUnderTest: HelloWorldViewModel

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        classUnderTest = HelloWorldViewModel(testDispatcher, doOperationUseCase)
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun doOperation() = runTest {

        coEvery { doOperationUseCase() } returns Result.success(listOf(""))
        assertEquals(HelloWorldState(), classUnderTest.state.value) // expected for initial state
        classUnderTest.state.test {
            classUnderTest.doOperation()
            assertEquals(classUnderTest.state.value.copy(loading = true), awaitItem()) // expected before calling doOperationUseCase use case
            assertEquals(classUnderTest.state.value.copy(loading = false), awaitItem()) // expected after calling doOperationUseCase use case
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
No value produced in 3s
app.cash.turbine.TurbineAssertionError: No value produced in 3s
```

Only test success when:

```
@Test
fun doOperation() = runTest {

    coEvery { doOperationUseCase() } returns Result.success(listOf(""))

    classUnderTest.state.test {
        classUnderTest.doOperation()
        assertEquals(classUnderTest.state.value.copy(loading = false), awaitItem())
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:1.8.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2")
testImplementation("app.cash.turbine:turbine:1.0.0")
testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.8")
testImplementation("com.google.truth:truth:1.1.4")
```

[Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test#stateflows) is not helpful as the repository controls when to emit a new value.

Comment: Your flow isn't emitting in the 'not working' one, which is kinda weird as `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` eagerly emits, it's worth double checking that everything emits like you think it does, we can't really see your impl here so can't say. Anyway, there's considerations using Stateflow and `UnconfinedTestDispatcher`, so you could try to replace it with `StandardTestDispatcher`, and experiment with using `runCurrent` / `advanceUntilIdle` and `expectMostRecentValue` to see if you get the emits you want. Maybe your non-emitting flow is due to a job queued by the test dispatcher that needs launched

Comment: And a suggestion about the impl I can't see - you don't need to pass the dispatchers object into your VM, you can just use `viewModelScope` in there, and in theory this should be the scope that gets replaced by your `@BeforeEach` logic (i.e., setting the test dispatcher). And it's probably a preference, but when I write tests like these I instantiate the VM fresh inside each test case - so there's nothing hanging around or from outside (you can also pass the scope you get from `runTest{...}` if/when you need to as well)